# SubQuery nHibernate without collection

Tags: nhibernate, collections, subquery, queryover

For example:

```
Tree treeAlias = null;

var nonRottenApples = QueryOver.Of<Apple>()
   .Where(a => !a.IsRotten)
   .Where(a => a.Tree.Id == treeAlias.Id)
   .Select(x => x.Id); //  <- optional
```

---

```
return NHibernateSession.QueryOver(() => treeAlias)
   .Where(t => t.Id.IsIn(ListOfTreeId))
   .WithSubquery.WhereExists(nonRottenApples)
   .List();
```

How do SubQuery not collection in Apple ?
I'm researching at various locations, but i not find results for my question.
All results are collections.

Comment: Graças Andrew! Mais ... A Apple não é a lista. Example :                  public class Tree { AppleDTO public virtual da Apple  } // obtém e define a relação é OneToOne

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is that you're trying to query for the trees that don't have rotten apples.

I believe this will work:

```
 var rottenTreeIds = QueryOver.Of<Apple>()
                             .Where(apple => apple.IsRotten)
                             .Select(a => a.Tree.Id);


 return NHIbernateSession.QueryOver<Tree>()
                         .Where(t => t.Id.IsIn(ListOfTreeId))
                         .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(t => t.Id).NotIn(rottenTreeIds)
                         .List();
```